# How to unlock and lock a button in my Quiz section

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently made a Quiz section on my app. In my quiz app, there are 4 categories. The easy, average, hard, and expert. I would like the 3 buttons to be locked while the easy round is not yet complete. and when the easy round is complete, the average will be unlock and so on. I tried doing multiple ways that I know could work, but I couldn't lock the buttons. I used the code I saw on youtube. But the code doesn't show how to lock it. So I don't know how. I am new to flutter and it will go a long way for me to master this. Please help me. I am stuck here. Thank you.

here is my code for the home:

```
import 'package:baybay_app/Quiz/QuizTracingSound.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:baybay_app/Quiz/QuizTracingSound.dart';

class QuizHome extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _QuizHomeState createState() => _QuizHomeState();
}

class _QuizHomeState extends State<QuizHome> {
  bool _isNextLevel;
  int question;
  String langname;
  bool isComplete = false;


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    List <String> images = [
      'assets/Ba.gif',
      'assets/GA.PNG',
      'assets/HA.PNG',
      'assets/SA.PNG'
    ];


   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Quiz Home '),
      ),
      body:ListView(
           children: <Widget>[
          CustomCard('Easy Round', images[0], des[0], isComplete = true),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      CustomCard('Average Round', images[1], des[1], isComplete),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      CustomCard('Hard Round', images[2],des[2], isComplete),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      CustomCard('Intermediate Round', images[3],des[3], isComplete),

           ],
      )

    );
  }
  List <String> des = [
    "The easy round lets you test your knowledge in determining letters. Are you up fpr the challenge? Click here!!!",
    "Do you want to step up your baybayin game? Lets see if you can distinguish words! Click here!!!",
    "Do you know how to construct sentences with the use of Baybayin? Click here!!!",
    "Masters of baybayin can only enter this quiz! Are you one of them? Click Here!!!",

  ];
 Widget CustomCard(String langname,images,String des, bool isComplete ) {

    return FlatButton(
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed:(){
        if(isComplete == false){
       showDialog(
         child: Text('Not complete')
       );
    } else{
          {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Quizjson(langname, isComplete),

            ));
          };
        }
        },

          child: Material(
            color: unlockColor,
            elevation: 10.0,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Padding(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                     vertical: 10.0,
                   ),
                   child: Material(
                     elevation: 5.0,
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                     child: Container(
                       height: 200.0,
                       width: 200.0,
                       child:ClipOval(
                         child: Image(
                           image: AssetImage(images),
                         ),
                       )
                     ),
                   ),

                 ),
                 Center(
                   child: Text( langname,
                   style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.white,
                     fontSize: 20.0,
                     letterSpacing: 10.0,
                     fontFamily: 'S'
                   ),),
                 ),
                 Container(
                   padding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   child: Text(
                     des,
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white,
                       letterSpacing: 1.0
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
              ),
            ),
          ),


    );
 }
 Color unlockColor = Colors.green;
 Color lockColor = Colors.grey;
  void unlock(){
      if(question == 10){
         isComplete = true;
         unlockColor;
      }
      else{
        isComplete = false;
        lockColor = lockColor;
      }


  }
}
```

and this is my code for the actual quiz.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:baybay_app/Quiz/NextLevel class.dart';
import 'package:baybay_app/Quiz/QuizHome.dart';
import 'package:baybay_app/Quiz/ResultPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Quizjson extends StatelessWidget {
  String langname;
  bool isComplete = false;
  Quizjson(this.langname, this.isComplete);
  String assettoload;
  int question;


  // a function
  // sets the asset to a particular JSON file
  // and opens the JSON
  setasset() {
    if (langname == 'Easy Round') {
      assettoload ='assets/Sample.json';
    } else if (langname == 'Average Round') {
       assettoload = 'assets/Medium.json';

    } else if (langname == 'Hard Round') {
      assettoload = 'assets/Hard.json';
    }else {
      assettoload = 'assets/Intermediate.json';
    }




  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    setasset();
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
          if(mydata == null){
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Loading",
                ),
              ),
            );
          }else{
            return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
          }

        }
    );
  }
}


class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
  String langname;
  var mydata;
  quizpage({Key key, @required this.mydata}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _quizpageState createState() => _quizpageState(mydata);
}

class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
  var mydata;
  _quizpageState(this.mydata);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Text(mydata[0][question.toString()])
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children:[
                    ChoiceButton("a"),
                    ChoiceButton("b")
                  ]
                ),
                Row(
                  children:  [
                    ChoiceButton("c"),
                    ChoiceButton("d"),
                  ]
                )
              ]
            ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
               showtimer,
                style:  TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }






Widget ChoiceButton(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 10.0,
          horizontal: 10.0),
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: ()=>CheckAnswer(k),
          child: Text(
          mydata[1][question.toString()][k ],
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          )),
          color: btncolor[k],
        ),
    );

}
  Color colorsToShow = Colors.brown[700];
  Color right = Colors.greenAccent[700];
  Color wrong = Colors.redAccent[700];
  int mark = 0;
  int question = 1;
  int timer = 30;
  String showtimer = "30";
  bool canceltimer = false;
  bool isComplete = false;

  Map<String,Color> btncolor = {
    "a" : Colors.brown[700],
    "b" : Colors.brown[700],
    "c" : Colors.brown[700],
    "d" : Colors.brown[700],
   };

  @override
  void initState(){
    starttimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn){
    if(mounted){
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  void starttimer() async {
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t){
      setState(() {
        if(timer < 1){
          t.cancel();
          NextQuestion();
        }
        else if(canceltimer==true){
            t.cancel();
        }
        else{
          timer = timer - 1;
        }
        showtimer = timer.toString();
      });
    });

  }

  void NextQuestion(){
    canceltimer = false;
    timer = 30;
    setState(() {
      if(question< 10){
        question++;
      }
      else{
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultPage(mark: mark),
        ));}
      btncolor["a"] = Colors.brown[700];
      btncolor["b"] = Colors.brown[700];
      btncolor["c"] = Colors.brown[700];
      btncolor["d"] = Colors.brown[700];
      isComplete = true;
    });
    starttimer();
}

  void CheckAnswer(String k) {
    if(mydata[2][question.toString()] == mydata[1][question.toString()][k]){
      mark = mark+1;
      colorsToShow = right;
    }

    else{
      colorsToShow = wrong;
    }
    setState(() {
      btncolor[k] = colorsToShow;
    });

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), NextQuestion);
  }

}
```

and this is the result:

```
import 'package:baybay_app/Quiz/QuizHome.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  int mark;
  ResultPage({Key key, @required this.mark}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ResultPageState createState() => _ResultPageState(mark);
}

class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {
  List<String> images = [
    'assets/excellent.jpg',
    'assets/good.png',
    'assets/Sorry.png'
  ];
  String message;
  String image;
  @override
  void initState(){
    if(mark<5){
      image = images[2];
      message = 'Try Again..\n' + 'You scored $mark';
    }
    else if(mark==5){
      image = images[1];
      message = 'Good.. \n' + 'You scored $mark';
    }
    else{
      image = images[0];
      message =  'Excellent!!!...\n' + 'You scored $mark';
    }
  }
  int mark;
  _ResultPageState(this.mark);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Result"
        )
      ),
      body: Column(
        children:[
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Container(
                child:Column(
                  children: [
                    Material(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 300.0,
                        height: 300.0,
                        child: ClipRect(
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              image,
                            )
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        message,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Staatliches'
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex:4,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children:<Widget>[
               OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> QuizHome()));
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Continue',

                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Staatliches'
                    )
                  ),
                   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 15.0),
                 borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3.0,color: Colors.brown[700])
                )
              ],
            )

          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just an aside, but I'd declare an enum for the various levels.  Using a string as a status level tends to not withstand maintenance well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in widget that is Ignore Pointer which will block all pointer-events while it is true. You could keep the ignore pointer to true while the user hasn't finished the easy part. Here is an Example of ignoring Pointer.

```
   // RaisedButton wrapped in IgnorePointer
      IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: true,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter1,
            color: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ), //Icon
          ), //RaisedButton
        ),
```

Comment: is it possible though if my quiz is in Json and the quiz is shared by one file?

Comment: No Problem at all. If it works for you then please consider accepting the answer. It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be to set null for onPressed of RaisedButton:

```
RaisedButton(
            onPressed: isEnable ? _incrementCounter1 : null,
            color: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ), //Icon
          ),
```